# How to get aggregated total and split of total sum which is also sum of items in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongo document similar as follows:

```
{"client" : "ashwini",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            .....

            "ac" : [ 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        5.0, 
                        0.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 10.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        52.0, 
                        0.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 22.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        85.0, 
                        0.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 50.0,on:false
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        5.0, 
                        50.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 30.0,on:true
                }
            ],
            "fan" : [ 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        10.0, 
                        20.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 50.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        60.0, 
                        20.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 10.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        85.0, 
                        20.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 40.0,on:false
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        10.0, 
                        70.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 10.0,on:true
                }
            ],
            "light" : [ 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        30.0, 
                        0.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 34.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        66.0, 
                        0.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 10.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        82.0, 
                        90.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 69.0,on:true
                }, 
                {
                    "cord" : [ 
                        20.0, 
                        50.0
                    ],
                    "power" : 70.0,on:true
                }
            ],
            "name" : "Palm Meadows",
            "floor" : -1.0
        }, 
        ......
    ]
 }
```

I want the output of my query as follows:

```
 {
        agr:{
          lights:10,
          ac:10,
          fan:20
        },
        split:[
          {
            name:"Palm Meadows",
            power:40,
            location:"Mahadevpura",
            lights:10,
            ac:10,
            fan:20
          },
       ....
       ],
}
```

where first agr is sum of all power in light/ac/fan field for client "ashwini" which are on and split has individual sum of light/ac/fan uniqued by name and location

I gave my first trial as follows

```
db.getCollection('property').aggregate([
                    {$match:{"client":"ashwini"}},
                    {
                        $group:{
                            _id:"$_id",
                            values:{
                                $addToSet:{
                                    name:"$data.name",
                                    floor:"$data.floor",
                                    location:"$data.location",
                                    lights:{$sum:"$data.lights.power"},
                                    fan:{$sum:"$data.fan.power"},
                                    ac:{$sum:"$data.ac.power"}
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ])
```

which gave output as follows

[image]

I'm not sure how to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4.

First part is to calculate the aggregate sum values for each location.

Second part is to aggregate sum values for all locations.

For each (`$map`) `data` row, `$filter` the data document where `on` field is true followed by  `$sum`ing the `power` value for each requested field (inner `$let`).

Outer `$let` expression to calculate the `power` values for each element which is the sum of requested fields along with aggregate requested field values, `name` and `location` as a `split` field inside `$project` stage.

Aggregate all the requested fields values across all locations as a `aggr` field inside `$addFields` stage which also retains the existing values.

```
db.getCollection('property').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"client":"ashwini"}},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "split":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$data",
        "as":"d",
        "in":{
          "$let":{
            "vars":{
              "ac":{
                "$sum":{
                  "$let":{
                    "vars":{"acm":{"$filter":{"input":"$$d.ac","as":"ac","cond":"$$ac.on"}}},
                    "in":"$$acm.power"
                  }
                }
              },
              "fan":{
                "$sum":{
                  "$let":{
                    "vars":{"fanm":{"$filter":{"input":"$$d.fan","as":"fan","cond":"$$fan.on"}}},
                    "in":"$$fanm.power"
                  }
                }
              },
              "light":{
                "$sum":{
                  "$let":{
                    "vars":{"lightm":{"$filter":{"input":"$$d.light","as":"light","cond":"$$light.on"}}},
                    "in":"$$lightm.power"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "in":{
              "name":"$$d.name",
              "location":"$$d.location",
              "power":{"$sum":["$$ac","$$fan","$$light"]},
              "ac":"$$ac",
              "fan":"$$fan",
              "light":"$$light"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$addFields":{
    "aggr":{
      "ac":{"$sum":"$split.ac"},
      "fan":{"$sum":"$split.fan"},
      "light":{"$sum":"$split.light"},
      "power":{"$sum":"split.power"}
    }
  }}
])
```

Use below query to output computed values for location and name.

`$unwind` data array followed by `$group` on location and name.

`$reduce` to traverse the grouped data to sum all the requested field values.

`$group` by _id to push the data values in array for computing values across all locations.

```
db.getCollection('property').aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$data"},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"id":"$_id","name":"$data.name", "location":"$data.location"},"data":{"$push":"$data"}}},
  {"$project":{
    "values":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":"$data",
        "initialValue":{
              "power":0,
              "ac":0,
              "fan":0,
              "light":0
            },
        "in":{
          "$let":{
            "vars":{
              "ac":{
                "$sum":{
                  "$let":{
                    "vars":{"acm":{"$filter":{"input":"$$this.ac","as":"ac","cond":"$$ac.on"}}},
                    "in":"$$acm.power"
                  }
                }
              },
              "fan":{
                "$sum":{
                  "$let":{
                    "vars":{"fanm":{"$filter":{"input":"$$this.fan","as":"fan","cond":"$$fan.on"}}},
                    "in":"$$fanm.power"
                  }
                }
              },
              "light":{
                "$sum":{
                  "$let":{
                    "vars":{"lightm":{"$filter":{"input":"$$this.light","as":"light","cond":"$$light.on"}}},
                    "in":"$$lightm.power"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "in":{
              "power":{"$add":["$$value.power", {"$sum":["$$ac","$$fan","$$light"]}]},
              "ac":{"$add":["$$value.ac", "$$ac"]},
              "fan":{"$add":["$$value.fan", "$$fan"]},
              "light":{"$add":["$$value.light", "$$light"]}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.id", "split":{"$push":{"name":"$_id.name","location":"$_id.location","values":"$values"}}}},
  {"$addFields":{
    "aggr":{
      "ac":{"$sum":"$split.values.ac"},
      "fan":{"$sum":"$split.values.fan"},
      "light":{"$sum":"$split.values.light"},
      "power":{"$sum":"split.values.power"}
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives split wrong where name and location pair is duplicated and comes as much item is present in "$data"

and value for "power" : 405.0,"ac" : 112.0, "fan" : 110.0,"light" : 183.0 are always same as these.

Comment: Yw. I've assumed data contains value for each location. Can you add a compete document to the post ? The current document is not complete like no location field.

Comment: try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CjN2qlfua9y08hqnQu5PxGYL508KkuW1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works for me. You have locations separated by floor. So you can add floor to the name and location and that will help you differentiate in the query like `"name":"$$d.name",
              "location":"$$d.location","floor":"$$d.floor"` in the outer `$let`

Comment: Thank you sir! Correct, it worked for me as well but I dont want it to saprate by floor I want agrigated power uniqued by  buildingName and and its location

Comment: Yw.That is one important detail you missed. It changes the whole question. Do you mind creating a new question ? You have to use unwind data, group on name and location and reduce to collect computed values.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll update the answer. Give me some time.

Comment: Did it work for you ? Let me know if you need anything.

Comment: It is not clear what query I have to write.. first or second one..?

Comment: second query to group by location and name